# Re-add ncpfs module to linux kernel 4.18, with Debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, dkms

I'm using Debian "testing".
At my work we have a Novell network and we are "forced" to use ncpfs. With kernel 4.18 this module/driver was removed from kernel.

Can someone explain how to re-add this module/driver? Maybe by using DKMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My co-worker built a RPM and I edited it for use with Debian and DKMS. If you need it, feel free to clone it [here](https://github.com/EnzephaloN/ncpfs_dkms). It's also available as stand-alone-module [here](https://github.com/EnzephaloN/ncpfs-module).